# Custom content type with a gallery and its "subgalleries" (or categorized gallery) in D7

Tags: entities, files, media

I have a content type with some custom fields, and I would like to have a gallery in it, with the images grouped into predefined "categories" - like a "subgallery".

For example, I have a *"building"* content type, and I would like to categorize the photos of it depending on of which part of the building (house) these photos were made or if they are simply *archive* photos, etc.: you can think of categories e.g. like *"Inside"*, *"Outside"*, *"Archive"*, *"Misc."*

I made a drawing to make it clearer:

[image: Content type with galleries and subgalleries]

What would be the best way to solve this problem?

Thanks for any kind of ideas!
Ask if anything is unclear.

---

In the meantime, I found a [Media Gallery](http://drupal.org/project/media_gallery) issue related to the topic:
[New feature: Gallery containers](http://drupal.org/node/1037002) (other related issues: [Hierarchical galleries](http://drupal.org/node/1273612), [Categorizing galleries](http://drupal.org/node/1115560))

Comment: IMHO it sounds like job for Node Reference. Did you check https://drupal.org/project/references? You can try to do it with taxonomy too.

Comment: @drupality: thanks for your answer, but how could I solve that when the end user creates a new content with this custom type, he/she would see an "in-place" uploading opportunity for the galleries? Or what alternatives can you imagine? I also thought about using [Media Gallery](http://drupal.org/project/media_gallery), but don't have a clue how to apply this for the given task.

Comment: If I remember good you can choose reference node from select list (e.g.) on your base node form.

Comment: @drupality: yes, OK, but my problem is that the user will be forced to create a gallery for the given content type **separately**, and later attach to this content, while this gallery doesn't really make sense on its own. So creating a separate gallery, and later attach to that node would be uncomfortable. :( Or do you know a good solution for that?

Comment: Sounds like you need to create custom module with form that allow you to create base node and gallery at once. Is this want you want?

Comment: @Sk8erPeter the [inline entity form](http://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) module will sort that bit out for you

Comment: @Clive: wow, that sounds great. If it is a possible solution, could you please post it as an answer? (Maybe a screenshot or two could be useful.) Thank you! Oh yeah, one more question. What about multiple languages? Do I have to create the galleries separately for all the enabled languages?

Comment: @Clive thanks guy to introduce inline entity form module which really was missed in Drupal 7. is there any plan for cover handling related models in D8?

Comment: Also if you have not complex sub-galleries, you can simply  create image field per sub-gallery.

Comment: @MohammadAliAkbari: I wouldn't have so complex galleries, I would like to have only exactly 6 of them. But even after attaching another gallery to the content type, I don't know how to categorize it well. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Clive: I opened a bounty for the question. If you could elaborate a little bit more on how to do the categorization exactly, it would be great, and I would gladly give the bounty to you. Inline Entity Form seems like a great start.

Comment: If you wont using inline entity form module and If your galleries is not complex (just images with their description), you can create one content type (gallery) with this fields:

 - title
 - body
 - custom field
 - gallery_archive (image field with unlimited cardinality)
 - gallery_outside (image field with unlimited cardinality)
 - 4 other galleries (image field with unlimited cardinality)

Comment: @MohammadAliAkbari: hmm, thanks for the idea, this seems like a good start! (In the meantime, I tried Inline Entity Form, but it seems like not working well for other content types which are not related to Commerce module.) But how to display the "subgalleries" (for example the images in the `gallery_archive` field) in a separate page? Maybe with Views, using arguments? What about multilingual content? Do I have to attach the images for each languages separately? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how well exactly this will fit in with your use case, but this is how I'd do it:

- Create a content type called "*SubGallery*", add an **Image** field to it with **unlimited** cardinality.
- Create the content type you want to contain the sub-galleries ("*Building*")
- Add an **[Entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference)** field to the "*Building*" type that references an **unlimited** number of "SubGallery" nodes.
- Choose "**[Inline Entity Form](http://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form)**" as the widget for that field, which will allow users to create the "*SubGallery*" content types within the same form as the "*Building*".

You can make use of the standard node title field for the name of the sub-gallery, or you might add a vocabulary called "*Gallery Type*", and add a field referencing that to the "*SubGallery*" content type. Then when your users add a new sub-gallery via the inline edit form, they can choose one of your pre-defined gallery types to associate with it.

If you do add the vocabulary and no longer need a node title for the sub-galleries,you could use [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle/) to fill it in automatically and hide it from the users.

Comment: Hi Clive, thanks for your answer and sorry for the late feedback. So, I have Entity Reference 7.x-1.0-rc3 and Inline Entity Form 7.x-1.0-beta3 installed. I created the "SubGallery" content type with an image field: http://i.imgur.com/HXoLZ.png. Then I created a "Building with subgalleries" content type with an Entity Reference field: http://i.imgur.com/e0Kxm.png. Here are the field settings: http://i.imgur.com/vOCci.png. BUT, when I try to create a node of the type "Building with subgalleries", the entity reference field doesn't show up: http://i.imgur.com/wA4pn.png. But why?!

Comment: Hmm that's odd, if you add a field it should definitely show up on the entity edit form. Could you try changing the widget to 'Image' instead of 'Media Selector' just to rule out any issue with that?

Comment: I tried that, changed the widget type to the regular Image: http://i.imgur.com/fg1Rb.png, but unfortunately the result is the same, the reference field doesn't show up. :( BUT after creating a SubGallery node, and changing the entity reference widget to e.g. "Select list" like this: http://i.imgur.com/h82KT.png, it shows up on the node creation form: http://i.imgur.com/ZBZ9S.png. But this way I can only reference **existing** nodes. So now it seems to me that Inline Entity Form doesn't work this way... I hope I'm not right! Any ideas? Have you tested it this way?

Comment: Just for testing, I installed Drupal Commerce, put a "Product reference" field in a test content type, set "Inline Entity Form" as a widget (like in the [screencast](http://commerceguys.com/blog/commerce-module-tuesday-inline-entity-form)), and with it, a product can be created "on-the-fly" without a problem. But unfortunately it seems like it doesn't work with "regular" entities like my "SubGallery"... So we are back again where we started... :( Do you have any alternative ideas? (or maybe a correction for the problem with Inline Entity Form)

Comment: +1. UPDATE: I found this issue: http://drupal.org/node/1713088, so others had similar problems like me; this problem seemed to have been solved in the Inline Entity Form **7.x-1.x-dev** version, BUT I still have a problem: I activated Automatic Nodetitles like this: http://i.imgur.com/bzT9L.png, which is correct (tried "separately", and works fine), but on the building node creation form, the title still appears, and while validation, I get this "mysterious" error: http://i.imgur.com/xgUgZ.png (mysterious, because I don't know which field is missing...).

Comment: Ah my bad, auto node title doesn't have support for IEF yet. There is [a patch](http://drupal.org/node/1719948) however, might be worth a try

Comment: ahh, thanks, I haven't seen this issue yet, I'll try that patch soon!

Comment: hmm, that's interesting, as a first try, now I simply disabled "Automatic title generation" for this content type: http://i.imgur.com/e3Tsb.png. But the validation error is just the same as before.... BTW, Theme developer is now completely DISABLED, so this can not be the source of the problem.

Comment: UPDATE (sorry for flooding you with comments :)): wow, after all it seems like Inline Entity Form DOES have an issue with Media module: after setting from [Media file selector](http://i.imgur.com/HXoLZ.png) back to [the regular Image field](http://i.imgur.com/fg1Rb.png), it seems to work perfectly as it should, look, here's a full screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/Kpn4o.png. "SubGallery" nodes can be edited and saved on-the-fly via AJAX, images can be added, categories can be selected with the radio buttons etc., so it seems very good! I think it was a good idea, I give you another feedback soon!

Comment: OK, first appearance: http://i.imgur.com/vAiK8.png, no thumbnails,etc. I enabled [Gallery formatter](http://bit.ly/9qiC4N),and set "Building with subgalleries" content type's display to "Rendered entity" like this: http://i.imgur.com/hfqUE.png,and set "SubGallery" type's Image field display to "jQuery Gallery": http://i.imgur.com/g3tXx.png. Now the result shows up like this: http://i.imgur.com/C8Sec.png. Close to what I would like to achieve! If you have any suggestions how to display exactly what I showed above, I'll be grateful if you tell me. But in fact you answered my question, thank you!

Comment: No probs :) There a probably a few different ways but I'd go with adding a new view mode for the gallery node (you can use [Entity View Mode](http://drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode) and providing a separate template for that view mode that mirrors exactly what you want to output. Then select that view mode in the manage display settings and you should be good to go